# How to clear error_get_last()?

Tags: php, function, error-handling

Code:

```
function load_file()
{
....
    if (($error=error_get_last())!==null) {
        $this->clear();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I need to clear error_get_last() after every time when i use this function.
How can i do it?

Comment: There's a feature patch for an [`error_clear_last()`](https://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg76560.html). For the time being, you'll have to use a workaround such as `trigger_error(NULL);` and handle that specific case.

Comment: A better trick is documented in the manual btw: http://php.net/manual/de/function.error-get-last.php#113518

Comment: Yep, I saw this trick, but i don`t know, how can i use it.

Comment: If you use eval() and have a syntax error in the expression then it looks like you won't be able to clear the error (in php 5.5, anyway

Answer (score 1):

Although I am late but for future reference the `error_clear_last()` is available in PHP 7. Get the last error using `error_get_last()` and clear it using the above function.

Note: Since PHP 7.2 `$php_errormsg` variable has been deprecated. See the PHP RFC for reference.

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_7_2